# Annotation for framework-used methods

Tags: java, spring, ide, apache-camel

I am currently a bit annoyed with my IDE, which is complaining about **unused methods**. These methods are used predominantly by `Camel` or `Spring` and not all covered by Unit Tests. I would like to annotate those methods to let my IDE know that they are unused for a reason.

**Which annotation is most suitable for this purpose?**

Comment: Can you post an example method?

Comment: @Priyesh any method would do - e.g. imagine the produce method of a spring bean that writes messages to a queue and is invoked by a camel endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @SuppressWarnings("unused")  ?

Comment: That is what I am currently using - I am not very happy with it since it suggests that "the method is unused but it is fine". I would rather have something analog to VisibleForTesting e.g. UsedByFramework